# can't install php-gd ext 7.0

Tags: php7

when i tried to install php7.0-gd i found this error

```
dfiadm@dc2-magneto-test:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-gd : Depends: libgd3 (>= 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: libxpm4 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

output of this command : apt-cache policy php7.0-gd

```
php7.0-gd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 7.0.33-57+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Version table:
     7.0.33-57+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     7.0.33-57+0~20211119.61+debian9~1.gbp5d8ba5 500
        500 https://packages.sury.org/php stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

my os ubuntu server LTS 20.04

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of PHP installed? 

Comment: only one version, but before i was installed more versions then removed all except 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Sury PPA + Ubuntu20.04 here. Those packages are fine and installable, but the problem in your case should be fixed by

```
apt install -f libgd3 libxpm4
```

To figure out what are your options for the package, you can use

```
apt-cache policy libxpm4
```

Which should give you something like

```
libxpm4:
  Installed: 1:3.5.12-1
  Candidate: 1:3.5.12-1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.5.12-1 500
        500 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: ("this is the output when i run this command" )

Package libxpm4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'libxpm4' has no installation candidate

Comment: @HamadAl-Shabrawi please check the apt-cache I have listed above.